# Python list comprehension for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

I'm reading [the Python wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Lists) and feel confused about this part:

> List comprehension supports more than one for statement. It will
> evaluate the items in all of the objects sequentially and will loop
> over the shorter objects if one object is longer than the rest.
>
> ```
> >>> item = [x+y for x in 'cat' for y in 'pot']
> >>> print item
> ['cp', 'co', 'ct', 'ap', 'ao', 'at', 'tp', 'to', 'tt']
> ```

I understand the usage of nested for loops but I don't get

> ...and will loop
> over the shorter objects if one object is longer than the rest

What does this mean? (shorter, longer...)

Comment: That explanation is useless. Someone writing it may have mixed it up with the behavior of `zip`.

Comment: @user2357112 I think you're right. Just look up zip function. With zip, the length of the objects matter because it will loop over the shorter one. Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

These type of nested loops create a [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the two sequences. Try it:

```
>>> [x+y for x in 'cat' for y in 'potty']
['cp', 'co', 'ct', 'ct', 'cy', 'ap', 'ao', 'at', 'at', 'ay', 'tp', 'to', 'tt', 'tt', 'ty']
>>> [x+y for x in 'catty' for y in 'pot']
['cp', 'co', 'ct', 'ap', 'ao', 'at', 'tp', 'to', 'tt', 'tp', 'to', 'tt', 'yp', 'yo', 'yt']
```

The **inner** 'x' in the list comprehension above (ie, the `for x in 'cat'` part) the is the same as the **outer** `for x in 'cat':` in this example:

```
>>> li=[]
>>> for x in 'cat':
...    for y in 'pot':
...       li.append(x+y)
# li=['cp', 'co', 'ct', 'ap', 'ao', 'at', 'tp', 'to', 'tt']
```

So the effect of making one shorter or longer is the same as making the 'x' or 'y' loop longer in two nested loops:

```
>>> li=[]
>>> for x in 'catty':
...    for y in 'pot':
...       li.append(x+y)
... 
>>> li==[x+y for x in 'catty' for y in 'pot']
True
```

In each case, the shorter sequence is looped over again until the longer sequence is exhausted. This unlike `zip` where the pairing would be terminated at the end of the shorter sequence.

### **Edit**

There seems to be confusion (in the comments) about nested loops versus zip.

Nested Loops:

As shown above, this:

```
[x+y for x in '12345' for y in 'abc']
```

is the same as two nested 'for' loops with 'x' the outer loop.

*Nested loops will execute the inner `y` loop the range of `x` in the outer loop times.*

So:

```
>>> [x+y for x in '12345' for y in 'ab']
    ['1a', '1b',   # '1' in the x loop
     '2a', '2b',   # '2' in the x loop, b in the y loop
     '3a', '3b',   # '3' in the x loop, back to 'a' in the y loop
     '4a', '4b',   # so on
     '5a', '5b']
```

You can get the same result with [product](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) from itertools:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> [x+y for x,y in product('12345','ab')]
['1a', '1b', '2a', '2b', '3a', '3b', '4a', '4b', '5a', '5b']
```

Zip is *similar* but stops after the shorter sequence is exhausted:

```
>>> [x+y for x,y in zip('12345','ab')]
['1a', '2b']
>>> [x+y for x,y in zip('ab', '12345')]
['a1', 'b2']
```

You can use [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) for a zip that will zip until the longest sequence is exhausted, but the result is different:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [x+y for x,y in itertools.zip_longest('12345','ab',fillvalue='*')]
['1a', '2b', '3*', '4*', '5*']
```

Comment: @drewk well, I understand the process, I just feel confused about the longer/shorter things the wikibook says, because clearly loops have nothing to do with the length of an object.

Comment: The wikibooks statement is wrong. What is does is loop over the *longer* of the two sequences as my example clearly shows.

Comment: @drewk yeah, what loops over the shorter object is zip function,right? Now I think I get it.

Comment: "What is does is loop over the longer of the two sequences as my example clearly shows" What are you saying? That the wikibooks statement is incorrect because it doesn't loop over the shorter one, but instead the longer one?

Answer (score 6):

Well, the Python documentation does not talk of any such short/long case: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions. Having two "for" in a list comprehension means having two loops. The example pointed by @drewk is correct.

Let me copy it for the sake of explanation:

```
>>> [x+y for x in '123' for y in 'pot']
['1p', '1o', '1t', '2p', '2o', '2t', '3p', '3o', '3t']
>>>
>>> [x+y for x in '1' for y in 'pot']
['1p', '1o', '1t']
>>>
```

In both cases, the first "for" forms the outer loop and hte second "for" forms the inner loop. That is the only invariant here.

Comment: yeah,I've Googled list-comprehensions and I didn't get any shorter or longer things... The way this wikibook says just makes me feel confused, both objects will get looped over and it has nothing to do with the length of an object, right?

Comment: Agreed. And the example also prove that the final values are identical for both cases (+1).