# Need help in understanding the (for loops) part of the statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, list-comprehension

```
([sum([abs(z-c) for y,b in zip(s,a) for z,c in zip(y,b)]) for a in pre])
```

I have used some for lop in python 3  but here i don't understand how these 3 for loops are working together are they seprate statements or anything else
Thanks in advance!!
Also Noob here(Obviously!!)

Comment: What exactly is it you don't understand? This is a list comprehension, you can write it as nested for loops if you want

Comment: [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18649916/8881141) on SO, translating list comprehensions into nested loops.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh as i understand from the python docs page the first two for loops can be written as this - `for y,b in zip(s,a): for z,c in zip(y,b):  list.append(abs(z-c))` but what about the third one `for a in pre`.... Can you please write the asked code in the simple for loops without list-comprehension Thanks –

Comment: http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/ might help too

Answer (score 1):

As ShadowRanger tagged, the magic phrase (to [look up](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atoms)) is “list comprehension” (see also the similar *generator expression*).