# What does "comp_for" mean in Python grammar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, grammar, context-free-grammar

I'm studying Python's grammar from the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/grammar.html), but I couldn't figure out what the `comp_for` production does. 
The production is called from the following productions: `testlist_comp`, `dictorsetmaker`, `argument`, and `comp_iter`.

What does `comp_for` stand for? In what cases it is used? I presume it derivate `for` statements, but why isn't the `for_stmt` production enough to generate `for` statements?

Comment: it's the `for` bits of a list / set / dict comprehension / generator expression

Comment: see this StackOverflow discussion: [Python list comprehension for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649884/python-list-comprehension-for-loops)

Comment: Thank you Anthony. I had no knowledge of the comprehension's existence. This make things a lot clearer :D