# Understanding the for loop in Python

Tags: python

```
ordered_list = [
    [i, j, k]
    for i in range(0, x+1)
    for j in range(0, y+1)
    for k in range(0, z+1)
    if i + j + k != n]
print(ordered_list)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

I am not understanding the working of for loops in this code. Can anyone please explain?

Comment: This is a list comprehension using a for loop . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649884/python-list-comprehension-for-loops a answer that explains this well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called list comprehension, you can see the link for more details.[Ref](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
# the code you listed above translate to this
ordered_list = []
for i in range(0, x+1):
    for j in range(0, y+1):
         for k in range(0, z+1):
            if i + j + k != n:
                ordered_list.append([i, j, k])
print(ordered_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a list comprehension equivalent to:

```
ordered_list = [] 
for i in range(0, x+1): 
    for j in range(0, y+1): 
        for k in range(0, z+1):
             if i + j + k != n:
                 ordered_list.append([i, j, k])
```