# different for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I always use

```
for letter in strings:
    j=letter.isalnum()
```

what does the line of code below mean?

```
letter.isalnum() for letter in strings:
```

What is the use of this kind of for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python list comprehension for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649884/python-list-comprehension-for-loops)

Answer (score 0):

The second line of code will produce a syntax error, it doesn't have a meaning. What does have a meaning is the use of comprehension like list-comprehension to pack values in a container data type, please look at the following example:

```
a = [letter.isalnum() for letter in strings]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another syntax you can use to run `for loop` with a small change i.e

```
j = (letter.isalnum() for letter in strings):
```

ans this is used to make `list`

example

```
squares = [i for i in range(10)]
>>> squares
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score -1):

if we wanted to remove all non alpha numeric characters from string, using list comprehension we use like. This is nothing but list comprehension , one of the power methods in python.

```
a='abcgd8&^9'
a1=[letter for letter in a if letter.isalnum() ]
a=''.join(a1)  #'abcgd89'
```

Comment: If you had tried to run your code and corrected the evident name error, you would have seen that it can't output what you say it does.